# interaction with hardware in c

Tags: c, winapi, function, pointers

calling a function by a pointer which hold the address of the function is generating error 
code:

```
p=GetProcAddress(h,"installhook");//p is a pointer that holds the address returned from getprocaddress() function
(*p)(); //using this pointer making a call to installhook function
```

but the code is generating error wher i am making a call by `(*p)();` it says term does not evaluate to a function.
how doi overcome with this?is there any other way making a call to the function using pointer?

Comment: Show us the declaration of p (as well as its type if it is a `typedef`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the return value of `GetProcAddress` to the correct function type. For example:

```
typedef void (*FuncPtr)();    //assuming a function like void f()
FuncPtr p;

p = (FuncPtr) GetProcAddress(h, "funcName");
if (p)
    p();
else
    printf("Function not found\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Verify `p` is declared like this:

```
void (*p)(void);
```

and that the type of the return value of `GetProcAddress` is the same.